# Magnesium has no unpaired electrons then why is it paramagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism

Paramagnetism is often associated with presence of unpaired electrons in atomic orbitals of atoms of the element.But magnesium has no unpaired electrons in it's atomic orbitals but still is paramagnetic.Why?Please explain.

Comment: Are you talking about Magnesium in a gas form, or solid form?

Comment: This might be a better fit for Chem SE.

Comment: I am talking about magnesium in solid form.

Comment: In the case of a metal it really doesn't make sense to say "magnesium has no unpaired electrons", there are valence electrons floating around and they are not "paired" in the atomic sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, but not always. In metals the free electrons contribute to the magnetic properties and this contribution is not related to atomic orbitals. See "Pauli paramagnetism" for example. The free electrons have a diamagnetic component too (Landau diamagnetism). The balance between all the contribution will determine the behavior of the metal (para- or diamagnetic).